# Flat tire with sidewall damage, slashing or driving damage?

Tags: tires, damage, sidewall-damage, sidewall

[image: my friend woke up and found his tire was flat in his driveway]

my friend woke up and found his tire was flat in his driveway

Comment: That's why we have yearly state inspections here in PA.  If your state does as well, I'd say the mechanic let your friend slide last time.  (or wasn't doing his or her job)

Answer (score 6):

The tire died of old age. He gave his life for the safety of the vehicles driver.

Snark aside:

Judging from the cracks that tire must be long overdue. Your friend can consider himself lucky. Should the blowout happened during a fast drive the consequences would have been serious.

But please, tell you friend to inspect the remaining tires and replace them if needed.

Comment: As in "perished".